# How to spin a circle while dragging around its center in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have vinyl disc image in the screen. The music should be played when you touch the center of the disc. The Question is **how to detect drag-spinning around the center of the disc** (so you can rewind-forward the sound). In other words a user touches the disc and moves its finger around the center of the disc. The disc should rotate and the music should rewind or forward.

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? if so, share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is:

1. attach DragListener to a circle (or even stage depends what you exactly need)
2. on dragStart() I would remember drag start point and stop playing music
3. on drag(event,x,y,pointer) I would calculate angle of vector **new Vector2((start.x + x) - center.x, (start.y+y) - center.y)** where center is the Vector2 type variable keeping circle center and start is Vector2 variable keeping start drag position - you also have to remember angle (for the first time just get an angle betweend **center** and **start**)
4. having the angle I would divide it by 360 then calculate a sound fragment length and play it forward or backward due to is angle higher or lesser than last time

The fragment length depends on "how long music is one full rotation of circle"

Remember to **set origin to the center of the circle** - otherwise it will be rotated arround its left corner

```
circle.setOrigin(Align.center); //assumin circle is Actor type (or inherits)
```